# Proving Convexity where the derivative is too complicated

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How to prove the following function is convex?

$F(x,y) = \frac{y}{x \ln \left(1+ \frac{y}{x}\right)}$ such that $x,y$ are non-negative variables.

I found that taking the second derivative is too complicated. Any suggestion? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t) = F(1,t)$. Show that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0} f'(t) = {1 \over 2}$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} f'(t)= 0$. In particular, $f'$ is decreasing and so $f$ is not convex and hence $F$ cannot be either.

In fact, it is sufficient to note that $f'(1) ={2 \log 2 -1 \over 2 ( \log 2)^2}>0$.